# How to make ListView to position under certain element?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, layout

I'm trying to put ListView under Toolbar but first item is getting set right in the toolbar, could you help me out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="invites_fragment"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        </TextView>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chatList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add property in `ListView`

`android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar”`

Comment: I was sure there is only android:layout_above property, thanks! But still first items renders in wrong way, maybe it's because im checking it on preview - haven't filled list yet so I can't check it emulator.

Comment: Ok nevermind Android studio had to think about it, it works. Thanks!